# How to retain only samples with same rowlengths in R?

Tags: r

I want to remove rows of `exp.normal` that ends with ".1" substring.
Then, I want to retain only rows where the rownames of `exp.normal` match another dataframe `exp.kirp`. I want to combine the dataframes column-wise.

My code returns the two dataframe with different row lengths.

```
exp.normal <- exp.normal[!is.infinite(rowSums(exp.normal)),]
exp.normal <- na.omit(exp.normal)

exp.normal <- exp.normal[!grepl('.1$', rownames(exp.normal)),]
exp.kirp.samp <- exp.kirp[rownames(exp.kirp) %in% rownames(exp.normal),]
exp.norm <- exp.normal[rownames(exp.normal) %in% rownames(exp.kirp.samp),]
```

Output:

```
> dim(exp.normal)
[1] 19947    32

> dim(exp.kirp)
[1] 12097   202
```

Traceback:

```
Error in cbind(...) : number of rows of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

Example data:

> dput(exp.norm)

```
structure(c(45.7005, 14525.5304, 2691.0051, 3648.1196, 3785.6462, 
508.7428, 3386.262, 1189.0624, 375.0458, 1767.0259, 27.3361, 
17196.2434, 2821.7784, 3730.9721, 8095.7046, 955.9156, 2899.3971, 
1115.2977, 457.7995, 1821.7784, 45.3806, 19112.246, 3016.1901, 
4261.1092, 9791.2504, 967.2683, 2105.4082, 795.0396, 419.566, 
1941.4399, 50.9688, 14891.6723, 3558.9722, 3323.9259, 4598.989, 
451.9671, 1407.3294, 410.278, 435.5518, 1647.4305, 108.6162, 
9145.2729, 2705.0238, 2702.0338, 991.7092, 820.278, 3857.5328, 
2015.6448, 332.5631, 1643.2139, 57.4382, 16482.7822, 2320.9426, 
2881.0338, 5242.4173, 434.1923, 2427.6701, 985.4808, 369.4413, 
1952.1095, 17.378, 16061.5305, 2530.1829, 4110.9756, 16517.6829, 
1559.0915, 1917.0732, 607.9268, 558.2317, 1896.3415, 20.626, 
16527.3632, 2925.5966, 4156.8309, 10196.4714, 635.9169, 2173.8045, 
781.4243, 469.7868, 1987.3547, 9.4012, 21390.7875, 2698.0142, 
4198.1283, 15663.0906, 1081.0287, 1256.9429, 591.6457, 585.8632, 
1796.5457, 70.6982, 36833.3219, 2334.0517, 3118.3636, 3214.0421, 
1119.1551, 2489.5293, 1626.5344, 372.9573, 1927.1034, 27.0724, 
41553.7462, 2221.6031, 3961.8517, 7251.1787, 1841.8174, 1867.5525, 
1033.0047, 366.9096, 2048.0069, 93.6277, 20812.3777, 3167.1196, 
3068.6141, 1033.9674, 238.3764, 3262.2283, 927.9891, 368.2065, 
1723.5054, 61.5543, 29531.5934, 3283.48, 3599.218, 531.7693, 
224.8289, 2014.6628, 1123.1672, 321.6031, 1888.563, 28.7045, 
14833.5053, 2878.5984, 3181.6764, 840.2164, 340.3734, 2266.8694, 
1306.6222, 430.3965, 1614.8444, 32.3228, 20450.3576, 2638.1234, 
3181.1024, 7459.6457, 791.6043, 2367.126, 982.2835, 444.2257, 
1665.3543, 9.6095, 16474.3224, 2779.0965, 4393.5681, 14546.3247, 
1160.0268, 1175.3446, 641.2711, 529.4793, 1929.9387, 33.5985, 
13559.3697, 2940.1548, 3312.0163, 741.4452, 493.1579, 4346.1672, 
1557.4905, 370.7226, 1643.4799, 26.9466, 26391.888, 2614.1732, 
3922.3097, 11886.2642, 1467.3491, 2908.8364, 740.1575, 431.4961, 
1638.1452, 51.9065, 20112.0953, 2840.2768, 3421.635, 1817.6237, 
567.9274, 2244.2088, 867.8801, 385.6534, 1525.9852, 91.0713, 
21614.0244, 2868.2575, 2628.6353, 408.8988, 486.2043, 1470.0472, 
2422.3217, 404.9217, 1386.5275, 28.0177, 16412.3814, 2963.8349, 
4044.6946, 7816.1037, 625.0426, 3087.001, 940.9758, 393.0399, 
1762.8796, 45.7438, 30459.0464, 2345.8452, 3155.2153, 9420.2711, 
1107.0516, 1614.3134, 818.9615, 484.3678, 1613.9445, 17.0691, 
14674.209, 3037.4688, 3741.8818, 5809.3256, 688.5928, 4134.4713, 
828.4763, 341.3822, 1690.2581, 44.1648, 12330.3918, 2558.2269, 
3040.4316, 2229.2957, 686.3165, 4200.9857, 959.8567, 420.3641, 
1570.6747, 17.6861, 19647.681, 2496.6604, 4041.9243, 6503.5269, 
749.796, 2689.1762, 1000.3566, 423.1116, 1590.8995, 41.1018, 
40847.6969, 2306.5671, 3025.5213, 3386.5546, 861.7896, 1909.7417, 
1051.6651, 394.6467, 1680.361, 53.3787, 12392.7638, 2879.6926, 
3503.1038, 7530.2986, 559.5507, 2631.9834, 796.9258, 437.1859, 
1609.8138, 20.4024, 15847.5751, 2082.0815, 2966.7382, 1372.3176, 
962.441, 1013.412, 810.0858, 478.0043, 1715.6652, 44.1964, 27787.4338, 
2517.8366, 3247.7944, 3787.8788, 680.8477, 2439.9693, 955.1208, 
431.5305, 2040.2762, 38.2464, 11097.4617, 3136.9164, 3515.104, 
1173.7936, 411.0357, 3917.6148, 1790.5061, 351.9027, 1664.5743, 
41.0752, 12219.0158, 3045.3933, 3753.4768, 371.6285, 612.8901, 
2541.1433, 1990.7641, 445.4353, 1827.0053, 29.0631, 22662.2977, 
2744.6112, 4235.6337, 13412.0641, 1127.8605, 1697.7296, 904.7316, 
513.0433, 1923.9901), dim = c(10L, 32L), dimnames = list(c("A1BG", 
"A2M", "AAMP", "AARS", "ABAT", "ABCA1", "ABCA2", "ABCA3", "ABCB7", 
"ABCF1"), c("TCGA-BQ-5887-11A-01R-1965-07", "TCGA-DZ-6133-11A-01R-1965-07", 
"TCGA-BQ-5884-11A-01R-1592-07", "TCGA-BQ-7044-11A-01R-1965-07", 
"TCGA-BQ-5888-11A-01R-1592-07", "TCGA-BQ-7051-11A-02R-1965-07", 
"TCGA-BQ-5879-11A-01R-1592-07", "TCGA-BQ-5882-11A-01R-1592-07", 
"TCGA-BQ-5894-11A-01R-1592-07", "TCGA-DZ-6132-11A-01R-1965-07", 
"TCGA-BQ-7045-11A-01R-1965-07", "TCGA-GL-A59R-11A-11R-A26U-07", 
"TCGA-P4-A5E8-11A-12R-A28H-07", "TCGA-P4-A5ED-11A-11R-A28H-07", 
"TCGA-BQ-7059-11A-01R-1965-07", "TCGA-BQ-5877-11A-01R-1592-07", 
"TCGA-A4-A4ZT-11A-11R-A26U-07", "TCGA-BQ-5891-11A-01R-1592-07", 
"TCGA-A4-A57E-11A-11R-A26U-07", "TCGA-BQ-7061-11A-01R-1965-07", 
"TCGA-GL-6846-11A-01R-1965-07", "TCGA-BQ-5890-11A-01R-1592-07", 
"TCGA-DZ-6131-11A-01R-1965-07", "TCGA-BQ-7055-11A-01R-1965-07", 
"TCGA-B9-4115-11A-01R-1758-07", "TCGA-BQ-5875-11A-01R-1592-07", 
"TCGA-BQ-7046-11A-01R-1965-07", "TCGA-GL-7966-11A-01R-2204-07", 
"TCGA-DZ-6134-11A-01R-1965-07", "TCGA-GL-A9DE-11A-11R-A37K-07", 
"TCGA-Y8-A8RY-11A-11R-A37K-07", "TCGA-BQ-5878-11A-01R-1592-07"
)))

> dput(exp.kirp)

structure(c(7.65342121905285, 14.3511850042327, 10.3737643425674, 
10.0819596419255, 9.44832324553207, 5.36085937172008, 9.78880184184623, 
10.3776687573505, 11.16757118884, 9.53872845925388, 9.59256168492636, 
11.6467250199966, 9.64995723240483, 7.72893066783674, 7.8938008505495, 
10.2355345297148, 4.7113572383413, 10.307474405626, 5.1591164988591, 
6.82029258613417, 11.8163747078537, 10.6949102196217, 11.2422803547626, 
8.59352109955772, 3.36085586100493, 9.85271363828624, 8.10771088195776, 
11.3942834720292, 7.22380769346318, 10.1931428909004, 8.38100686984167, 
10.16821542222, 7.89538927254103, 9.15267449482738, 10.3931817074315, 
12.7214881212179, 10.1435311751243, 11.5928015984057, 9.61257956084687, 
6.32433538607651, 9.96819071167712, 10.0874192149778, 10.14614948871, 
9.68818857795196, 10.4090748876599, 10.6687443412299, 10.8848143975244, 
11.5872726722286, 6.84628770347992, 10.2373774088459, 5.09389393824392, 
12.4136523086721, 11.1918237390263, 10.1912122382252, 9.9623840324273, 
6.22565668754941, 10.3398477765017, 10.3103072842012, 11.1287210937383, 
9.12552428380532, 10.0220514952103, 11.5514020529076, 9.33154847897224, 
7.15215907641367, 8.30013562492319, 10.2772713571793, 3.07471093384149, 
9.90686083971644, 5.84486014570242, 7.85453119568792, 10.1727165187711, 
11.3218051787965, 11.6207019570471, 8.14964399360302, 2.57221059331231, 
9.770250762185, 8.2978654585063, 11.084297043801, 5.60196387752462, 
8.88994408176988, 8.11137409958519, 10.6640911447013, 7.63002607924622, 
8.98301980527478, 9.95231536364664, 9.50590581220822, 12.3983662709548, 
9.74297479204394, 9.19670588373063, 5.03164662255944, 9.10229620506499, 
10.4765987884097, 10.4203162794891, 9.17212793704954, 10.6963363394643, 
10.517658858193, 10.6383042190661, 9.89639568127639, 4.96453263672961, 
10.153415608879, 4.70168212029528, 10.1689338100564, 9.96839262629172, 
9.87305770150294, 9.75535162798677, 6.170389794965, 10.238532641469, 
9.94050095178643, 11.0690397931313, 9.18120494347434, 10.1026705963882, 
12.2134644534149, 9.76558563096394, 7.17400985460863, 8.51390402420206, 
10.6841464369114, 4.46450490913191, 10.2220147915752, 6.26732229936107, 
8.34111937214434, 9.4563488702199, 11.3165579369515, 11.3692227748971, 
7.56443152168505, 3.28865386360517, 9.3642795739989, 7.97047579449743, 
4.39174710202512, 1.99320334863612, 9.09364811306327, 7.99728901996415, 
11.0296194917623, 7.76961109298212, 9.33304596974955, 9.89296486273821, 
13.2154969925887, 10.5733689401427, 10.0743768517653, 8.12622125684463, 
4.20618996652279, 9.22288882589791, 10.7973270736212, 10.0356016423526, 
9.9017250769121, 10.2083981309069, 11.6540022938525, 11.3739522748552, 
8.46892945061225, 3.85569076543445, 10.0627068729804, 7.99645936536463, 
13.6832285748428, 10.3714563849361, 10.4176870383992, 10.0652444551968, 
5.98935248863472, 10.1079093507719, 11.2050505161752, 11.6645692817891, 
9.14131578384568, 10.4504026669882, 11.7286541625055, 9.0418201112886, 
7.18088382351455, 8.02888128245278, 10.4406656190814, 4.29335576875801, 
9.41768714387146, 5.17869870850833, 6.88790782664042, 10.6188892562694, 
10.3842123858415, 11.7658466970944, 7.8638220194434, 4.34994552290862, 
9.22504206592907, 7.63249652719248, 10.3723102883537, 5.34994198553451, 
9.48564780343169, 8.04610739496541, 10.4463535299365, 7.68066614055097, 
9.04610766787879, 9.95556447653129, 11.8525448023587, 10.4640851987958, 
10.4308625115247, 9.91159766583895, 5.37742225475561, 9.4487843137183, 
9.99933682779041, 10.2770366214296, 9.0418201112886, 10.5578953924552, 
10.4808099887997, 10.9764939558956, 10.4242897631097, 4.93490330712903, 
10.9389453617464, 5.13719199914349, 12.0367193976262, 10.8202555636581, 
10.3262700402849, 9.91216810777653, 5.52284042813955, 10.0653680664815, 
10.5954686012028, 11.2355920880251, 9.10909645558853, 9.94472260124272, 
11.5783590097537, 9.29504775099388, 7.53455423776441, 9.73144632203062, 
10.3357853667922, 2.69972929338667, 11.0827581319988, 5.12711734972685, 
7.20385010562547, 10.2823150418909, 9.98084618229907, 10.5982618153731, 
8.87118417188149, 4.52284042813955, 8.94910562068286, 8.00490358291707, 
11.0657044429112, 7.06536766254031, 8.7728136979997, 8.38298319671723, 
10.0327018868117, 7.20326283373569, 9.47196961605789, 9.90466577812603, 
9.49413435666035, 10.19403569598, 10.4724772111563, 11.1448925980171, 
7.28004970633421, 9.06939981937328, 10.8754120177161, 10.2352930230415, 
9.35902847180107, 10.7267739242029, 10.5529081501417, 11.2956215011293, 
8.85725977829128, 4.55387039485638, 11.0056049014623, 6.95117512427229, 
10.9656928148969, 10.5991523452113, 10.4556415168452, 9.46537845450025, 
6.72337288854289, 10.0139441477751, 9.28408724134641, 11.4833270722276, 
9.49617650025352, 10.4425557194467, 11.449658606754, 8.69606512512137, 
6.7730033396692, 9.79804905625499, 10.6006257403548, 6.41043269493023, 
9.33218159403931, 6.79787807595744, 3.66448284036468, 9.36947738932311, 
12.1844424384667, 11.1649886100581, 8.30833493415398, 1.07949758402178, 
8.50996853808744, 8.25444192773356, 11.0514188710826, 7.25444192773355, 
10.2092692396731, 8.12117551878819, 10.7242737250263, 7.07511328163257, 
9.24190737941017, 9.38899238984847, 11.5242722006977, 10.8138023505891, 
9.39692881604932, 7.33690372047785, 5.99837831118633, 9.20104960820531, 
10.271192322104, 10.3421982587672, 9.9583334671237, 10.8104108086575, 
11.3588364978417, 10.3011032299907, 9.79976033549459, 4.03371371384131, 
9.4502035528435, 3.61712213221935, 11.9975977242282, 9.91379851626213, 
9.95999222715916, 9.90779350021794, 7.85831302551685, 10.3997246047534, 
11.7402171909708, 11.7246448152361, 9.75167259046219, 9.68598603763708, 
11.889881014998, 10.3276744540453, 8.04315308658688, 9.09516358798289, 
10.1351204181247, 2.58736499093646, 10.6921133041207, 6.09727578619146, 
10.2388193351428, 11.1387141417635, 9.60973686632844, 9.91029869099744, 
7.0969238361025, 1.22478119439559, 7.85207251858217, 8.9132990393591, 
11.4041748741886, 7.92325557174226, 11.9555213595621, 8.66299657133128, 
9.99675988081849, 6.52046939465285, 9.19469924394784, 11.4453499696318, 
13.7764385227361, 10.9582985177207, 9.73202730526663, 11.8793070895146, 
5.674830656291, 9.30694800222568, 11.6556994451055, 10.4213132544326, 
10.4922544904181, 10.5534738814693, 10.6996637140919, 10.2332275555211, 
9.52531486289245, 6.37164075239763, 11.3566558699168, 3.15639661659767, 
10.9506421354115, 10.8015070949819, 9.51027580369917, 10.0114476969219, 
5.9232585434528, 10.1410206692489, 10.9093204661635, 11.1601119970792, 
9.35889972298825, 9.89445931817658, 11.7097666903094, 10.3085136675886, 
7.97175793055237, 9.39274501543653, 10.3787624907905, 6.94163806584425, 
11.8483258820978, 5.28766436585954, 6.24271872469928, 10.0904144275087, 
10.7658517928209, 10.6194247493219, 8.72532024089938, 6.12970957941129, 
7.37932464409351, 8.97175821789909, 13.5632882613554, 6.31028194625214, 
8.64822705939532, 9.18732138776524, 10.4159346076083, 6.46711478729057, 
8.74638197005123, 9.80945126361765, 11.0458332956411, 12.6596471469673, 
7.83425486655716, 10.9194011668402, 4.66760264911311, 8.44306371542639, 
11.6735729859861, 10.592053792505, 10.0394481089966, 10.738081785684, 
10.6804287993454, 10.4484290791818, 8.73413344315171, 6.43659995275074, 
10.6685246199734, 8.20162111992077, 12.7954861179578, 10.0094938620897, 
9.93400880935778, 9.75330735360058, 7.0082672553098, 9.74081003982032, 
10.7382235152475, 11.6720072357516, 8.44494819471576, 9.99223068991282, 
11.0703963722836, 9.47126368282115, 7.81421970385892, 9.50816775056871, 
11.4983748936735, 6.23485957395859, 11.5903647810385, 6.26655044400704, 
5.21798676951157, 10.0355914707199, 10.2338111446746, 11.8068330986116, 
7.98850462265062, 2.26801511865652, 8.75403900144463, 8.99470954056443, 
13.8050246222504, 9.39637273263616, 9.25174607188694, 8.59323012958596, 
9.64227593422842, 7.73613603148148, 8.71848835304267, 11.3433845026852, 
11.2390478373181, 10.8940677306605, 10.8800576375586, 10.6070670903737, 
5.6912382257558, 9.46054395023954, 9.9164661944151, 9.35162700413489, 
9.86387775885121, 10.0058120312308, 10.7880204671486, 10.3793997040699, 
9.6038232649825, 4.26803009485916, 10.2782371039023, 6.26475409489153, 
12.8198023802381, 11.7916439373724, 9.53606689182685, 10.3591574288036, 
5.71406413888836, 10.0630462305102, 10.2195932783632, 11.455724780085, 
8.42239448735832, 9.24745049099849, 12.1236985893816, 9.92518871297862, 
7.89993146943836, 8.72944026793844, 10.4251666934438, 3.90670784266208, 
9.20041190448898, 6.65613736826174, 10.2389705995139, 9.53818563335118, 
11.7495320050765, 12.0646887131882, 8.44896824561834, 3.71406963555001, 
9.8415805435622, 8.31270283399943, 5.24299494486063, 6.49167354977479, 
9.98614168480194, 8.4582261368972, 9.59531026428392, 8.57655917226128, 
8.95437954428976, 10.6495249285462, 14.9290954211312, 10.5422470205379, 
9.17443338491354, 3.94233621005718, 5.67224428652735, 8.7869060376421, 
10.8632316688763, 9.68413003969761, 10.0472843996015, 10.3973606067328, 
10.2873877943623, 10.1185985217259, 9.54984491532867, 3.90670784266208, 
8.67224499381939, 5.31084177712261, 13.1978705809921, 9.83862580682156, 
9.54417855835282, 10.3479785104067, 6.95803180123955, 10.5275135616911, 
10.7557094705532, 11.5723066760841, 9.32468663898682, 9.95090752477796, 
11.895394953164, 10.1730449599892, 7.96865297090106, 8.25269807010003, 
10.3946717952085, 3.87765591897716, 9.72523791794449, 6.55356786048423, 
6.95803180123955, 10.5069909263905, 10.2877565830483, 10.5166977513248, 
8.4726051481255, 4.38016145559557, 8.85875002019905, 8.67423888569003, 
8.68286505123176, 5.31506259026344, 10.3333282396821, 9.31228692654063, 
10.4142296315944, 7.85981553329836, 8.44751431678991, 11.0858929239232, 
9.28987549215634, 11.1939401219005, 9.81036549777261, 8.34254452326977, 
5.73563860631975, 9.00522312099486, 10.3688436329726, 9.94464471906402, 
10.1522308353126, 10.7920437057173, 10.4456146711682, 10.5376544440661, 
9.5106538108757, 6.00694202058687, 10.5239172935582, 6.07015744755466, 
13.1209957412573, 10.9576837919022, 9.8945869439465, 9.23740931858995, 
4.16326524153571, 10.523017510386, 10.532865308348, 10.619622367405, 
9.45558963540716, 11.5136546699209, 11.209027561542, 8.50311772962086, 
6.94462773667725, 9.43239470040379, 10.9762474117231, 3.74822505823549, 
8.22396403818439, 5.28179467379438, 5.07015744755466, 9.40882053452885, 
9.15195265459219, 11.7917134419519, 8.19669113197608, 4.74823042627325, 
10.2400835226029, 7.76318049103673, 10.5252116829711, 5.07015744755466, 
9.41356636990191, 8.69464935705204, 10.5448108847847, 6.4670479262821, 
8.25602512546126, 10.0954826060933, 9.24807628369884, 10.2848014332547, 
9.6103510748559, 7.88436713970017, 6.04591033802914, 7.98344684046261, 
9.83392420760322, 10.426537121557, 8.77797787921888, 11.1932452952465, 
10.889486091222, 10.329430966151, 9.26655583156462, 3.62269612816767, 
10.5609425545211, 5.59521719360418, 13.9452588877727, 11.136365018286, 
10.0338699199786, 9.01178744914112, 7.04236745871339, 9.77739489226773, 
10.1944306108943, 11.0829417734315, 9.2483306049673, 10.2526052400654, 
11.2392043296817, 9.78826123015354, 7.37009277188134, 9.28978490856306, 
10.770835486621, 4.07112766139071, 8.79617819177588, 6.50274907789938, 
4.95248267443048, 10.0124053945822, 10.8791588020481, 10.1400457232732, 
9.64018220112663, 7.9855897990336, 8.44341851204054, 8.1851425389976, 
11.3009567982918, 7.87032217794857, 9.12571179465448, 8.10396912418597, 
10.0952450966319, 7.11418480239357, 9.3240403215499, 9.55790821677093, 
12.5506935970456, 11.2890199649612, 9.74578287914873, 8.83302700041379, 
6.80619256918401, 8.91595554395471, 10.4010993451482, 10.426361210739, 
9.65687923171916, 10.3180541086121, 10.2515587448026, 10.4679560946132, 
9.3710569683502, 5.63055399711973, 9.66161458306801, 3.49639843291562, 
12.046947416625, 7.48250063297666, 10.3197777792499, 9.47365522397164, 
6.95629018836077, 9.81146637438849, 9.67304984423569, 11.9690923038785, 
9.99940969863312, 10.4101699932371, 12.2230772873117, 9.90523370112278, 
7.10116469832952, 8.84409058546722, 11.2100883041446, 2.89400283481279, 
12.1723192712031, 7.02813039834545, 7.76654547216671, 9.33005660517673, 
9.71268261052322, 10.1695833227844, 7.83721098924632, 1.12849137851042, 
7.14639353071401, 7.90194088386521, 10.2858186675831, 4.09194519835092, 
9.82683604431664, 9.28935150377015, 10.3990006824976, 7.03632419457704, 
9.25259305937555, 9.96009564626238, 13.6495813760682, 11.2087562804992, 
8.62991100391626, 10.8093586506308, 4.36112967113519, 8.66452479510135, 
10.680372183305, 10.4092425218598, 10.166842081886, 11.1148826551454, 
11.5218621620828, 10.8830252212276, 8.50698349076537, 6.57472823565416, 
10.546746035965, 7.53012147669141, 15.4681548425702, 9.79693513247838, 
9.38793395115019, 8.98389796929759, 5.4990039364996, 9.68780798972713, 
10.2221443965538, 11.2238327266469, 8.86631579791574, 9.0839648421511, 
11.7688762222962, 9.43339244300495, 7.75707059749995, 7.30848010698361, 
10.3788698682696, 5.10854118358023, 9.397938764198, 5.14397700761083, 
5.54294517859488, 11.3477092783888, 10.1821779329165, 10.5068822633094, 
7.95165772727702, 6.07899829224459, 9.17521394310747, 8.44018606106649, 
10.2131062858423, 5.98655201209625, 9.76585079853419, 8.60644889080884, 
9.71847037220014, 7.04446188071599, 9.27521498813589, 10.9901943954469, 
11.5209125420426, 9.65147026322989, 10.6316810922306, 5.74458092333422, 
8.26977703134258, 10.0141332026215, 9.03736135461269, 9.96719613631738, 
9.93388860627356, 10.7248434525252, 10.2215812006449, 10.3621030533842, 
11.4668080776894, 7.99184662847717, 9.33580121861008, 5.66820140316967, 
11.9947030005322, 9.64794224178718, 10.1925126545798, 10.2674620603105, 
7.5327081297796, 9.69101099541322, 11.2548391298699, 11.7689577047578, 
9.19050300947907, 9.56006949444913, 11.2747943605218, 10.0095406093405, 
8.00727063981421, 9.97974599674609, 10.3602156709497, 3.94458674388554, 
12.5277668843542, 5.61301589155362, 10.2348465241763, 11.2408106474539, 
10.7817980294952, 11.3929731417988, 8.56239088440517, 2.39709102017243, 
8.66820104853111, 9.02757458085238, 12.6567500587125, 6.6095466615844, 
11.4664830513311, 8.87780988126623, 10.3650994493445, 8.35292135920633, 
7.93983129663749, 9.4812924824758, 12.99012924981, 10.4898544816469, 
8.58540087815148, 10.8618786972288, 7.71067834148438, 8.93864071660805, 
11.4031536223651, 10.7979767770093, 9.84830839236378, 9.47801724034487, 
10.6468489299639, 10.3611048811716, 8.96812071185483, 5.42457950821431, 
10.7176375280321, 5.99997294921438, 11.249476392449, 10.9207261360998, 
10.3485991467441, 9.01994649367039, 6.53868559158395, 9.41478373733666, 
10.432374028565, 11.0171355028297, 9.38017184771789, 10.5614675309011, 
11.5465057188577, 9.17787519818794, 7.04065904752138, 11.0984136358699, 
10.7076152049804, 2.37928824997193, 12.014117542008, 6.92057199739813, 
4.98912992235826, 10.120606346187, 10.2084736088023, 10.4873799256012, 
9.27923169328214, 1.52972101613862, 9.22178985762886, 7.95596194920281, 
12.8045414410067, 7.92201464494711, 9.47902214483086, 7.4885399127133, 
10.1807490909157, 6.70138409679205, 9.69962242189537, 10.1778751981879, 
9.210584414225, 10.547619289895, 10.7420721677751, 11.6561438053443, 
5.89426967756534, 9.09193991076902, 10.4509432609399, 10.2168981211661, 
9.50697734395297, 10.1421973186731, 10.289252816822, 11.0579561962947, 
8.44378357961471, 4.8801957289431, 11.4458754454719, 4.65344988200111, 
12.0454913320053, 10.7230307474822, 9.54770815725829, 9.91346136214138, 
6.41298301444827, 10.2791008470934, 11.2856294138809, 11.2550839389669, 
9.39663175119314, 10.3644682533465, 12.3720956896476, 9.96448281969001, 
7.26859346154833, 9.52846036210416, 10.6382351536235, 4.31017286300409, 
11.0690011128305, 5.82641628715103, 6.80493638177069, 9.89786451034248, 
9.94481833785949, 11.6774877172589, 9.01061202172265, 6.17266952106643, 
9.5752544613585, 8.43194131360949, 11.0206656082034, 7.72110534236959, 
10.5081439758347, 8.68994452434197, 10.8685929396885, 6.5444359272107, 
8.68679113793189, 10.8525006396094, 11.1533795693109, 11.5873539730162, 
8.99794551516942, 9.87102611145061, 3.93820109105871, 9.06141196830279, 
10.3168170965086, 10.0968873453464, 9.78516864210074, 10.6089638880433, 
10.6772891469749, 10.6027030400136, 10.5354892373923, 5.69623034672501, 
10.4314703380043, 3.77147362287765, 11.9414284466395, 8.62911943026167, 
9.47885474304884, 9.32603460205856, 7.52941181265447, 10.1897935554257, 
10.6869529617348, 10.9824945325978, 9.54925041577186, 9.24348510543789, 
12.6197561225204, 10.4229927556855, 7.78641143939821, 10.3518043181888, 
10.2176900900617, 2.72462844562171, 13.9420477990178, 6.05669840185354, 
8.84668667779751, 10.976770882955, 11.2310420929738, 11.9128532309879, 
8.82897202130395, 2.92626515369416, 9.02841610083176, 9.70477480883974, 
13.4396963975546, 6.34522248637767, 10.2353559766448, 8.78641143939821, 
10.5578417013582, 6.64287771079513, 9.06181129266044, 10.6360273009065, 
12.9150155941383, 11.9719694740862, 8.95056581144122, 10.0640399701312, 
7.2355968744756, 9.21728961537032, 11.5561009223631, 9.95201054312933, 
10.0229270264038, 10.7583335783419, 10.7564054571028, 10.3137246220883, 
8.76465102394471, 5.79502400957859, 9.85443348382268, 5.2076547248541, 
12.2695992772649, 10.7969615679355, 9.78033864553782, 9.39835742542764, 
6.02727350425616, 9.5278442796299, 11.038246992221, 11.1457431696807, 
9.00232447215102, 9.03646624386732, 12.062072892785, 10.0526651781329, 
7.29576250712518, 7.86933843816656, 9.61223637364334, 3.32380238041871, 
8.70355167900769, 5.73415681989236, 8.69454663545621, 11.3998442086989, 
11.3703586767908, 12.3235644563292, 9.05367152133834, 10.196743500022, 
9.91601721982026, 8.03544796058228, 12.1704251930224, 5.87162190579696, 
8.07993112355535, 8.03136652207373, 9.91767640083016, 5.98915036355025, 
9.10990689967612, 11.1609999554059, 11.726925238744, 12.2657872278982, 
9.73588750953117, 11.4370505772681, 5.57906848944612, 9.27950936832482, 
9.65861638042757, 9.17054127127384, 9.78579998093652, 10.5632561528303, 
10.254342831578, 10.148100924125, 10.2726105411389, 4.18254929202166, 
10.6197309312023), dim = c(50L, 20L), dimnames = list(c("A1BG", 
"A2M", "A4GALT", "AAAS", "AACS", "AADAT", "AAGAB", "AAK1", "AAMP", 
"AARS2", "AARSD1", "AARS", "AASDHPPT", "AASDH", "AASS", "AATF", 
"AATK", "ABAT", "ABCA11P", "ABCA12", "ABCA1", "ABCA2", "ABCA3", 
"ABCA5", "ABCA6", "ABCA7", "ABCB10", "ABCB1", "ABCB4", "ABCB6", 
"ABCB7", "ABCB8", "ABCB9", "ABCC10", "ABCC1", "ABCC3", "ABCC4", 
"ABCC5", "ABCC6", "ABCC9", "ABCD1", "ABCD3", "ABCD4", "ABCE1", 
"ABCF1", "ABCF2", "ABCF3", "ABCG1", "ABCG2", "ABHD10"), c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A", "TCGA.4A.A93W.01A", 
"TCGA.4A.A93X.01A", "TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A", "TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A", "TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A", 
"TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A", "TCGA.A4.7288.01A", "TCGA.A4.7583.01A")))
```

Comment: There is no `.1` - `grep("1$", row.names(exp.normal), value = TRUE)#
[1] "ABCA1" "ABCF1"`
 but it is just that the `.` matches any character if it is not fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `intersect`

```
nm1 <- intersect(row.names(exp.normal), row.names(exp.kirp))
exp.kirp.samp <- exp.kirp[nm1,]
exp.norm <- exp.normal[nm1,]
dim(exp.norm)
#[1]  8 32
dim(exp.kirp.samp)
#[1]  8 20
```

---

In the sample data showed, there are no `duplicates` for row names.  It may be better to check for any duplicates with frequency count on the row names

```
> table(row.names(exp.normal))

 A1BG   A2M  AAMP  AARS  ABAT ABCA2 ABCA3 ABCB7 
    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 
> table(row.names(exp.kirp))

    A1BG      A2M   A4GALT     AAAS     AACS    AADAT    AAGAB     AAK1     AAMP     AARS    AARS2   AARSD1    AASDH AASDHPPT 
       1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1 
    AASS     AATF     AATK     ABAT    ABCA1  ABCA11P   ABCA12    ABCA2    ABCA3    ABCA5    ABCA6    ABCA7    ABCB1   ABCB10 
       1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1 
   ABCB4    ABCB6    ABCB7    ABCB8    ABCB9    ABCC1   ABCC10    ABCC3    ABCC4    ABCC5    ABCC6    ABCC9    ABCD1    ABCD3 
       1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1 
   ABCD4    ABCE1    ABCF1    ABCF2    ABCF3    ABCG1    ABCG2   ABHD10 
       1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1
```

If there are duplicates,  it is not clear about the logic for processing based on the post.